# The drunken blind man’s walk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider a drunk, blind man starting in the middle of the two dimensional open unit ball. At each turn, the man chooses a direction to move a step of size $\delta > 0$ in. Unfortunately, he is very drunk, so he has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of moving in the reverse direction instead! Further, he is blind, and without a cane so he does not know where he is after each step.

Formally, we write $(x_n, \theta_n)$ for the position and orientation of the man, where we start at $x_0 = 0$, $\theta_0 = 0$. A *strategy* is a sequence of angles $\phi_n$, chosen in advance.

Let $\epsilon_n$ be a sequence of iid Bernoulli random variables, taking values $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. Denoting by $R_{\theta}$ the rotation by angle $\theta$, and writing $v := (\delta, 0)$, his position and orientation are then updated according to the rule

$$(x_{n+1}, \theta_{n+1}) = (x_n + R_{\theta_n + \phi_n + \epsilon_n \pi} v, \theta_n + \phi_n + \epsilon_n \pi).$$

**Question:** What is an optimal strategy for the man to take to minimize the expected time to exit the ball?

Comment: I'm confused about the direction choice. How does he choose a direction? Is it absolute or with respect to how he's oriented? Is he oriented the same way he went in the previous step?

Comment: @user479223 That's a very good point. If he is blind, the direction choice should be with respect to how he's oriented since he wouldn't have enough info to make an absolute choice. He should be oriented the same way he went in the previous step. I will add this to the original post.

Comment: Shouldn't $v$ be $(\varepsilon, 0)$, not $(1,0)$?

Comment: @CommandMaster Indeed. I have changed it to $\delta$ to avoid confusion with the random variables $\epsilon_n$.

Comment: How about a variant where the man *can* see where he is, and he wants to *maximize* the amount of time he spends inside the ball?

Comment: @SamHopkins: Except for tiny details, this is the same problem and also answered by Ofer's analysis: The time takes care of itself if we only maximize the distance from the circle when we do leave. (If the disk were closed, it would be clear-cut: we can do what we want as long as not close to the boundary, and when we get within distance $\delta$, we must aim at the boundary exactly and then continue in the radial direction.)

Answer (score 6):

The expected exit time (from a ball of radius 1) is $(1+o_\delta(1))/\delta^2$, regardless of the choice of strategy (the $o_\delta(1)$ term does depend on the strategy). Indeed, write $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i v_i$
where $v_i$ are the steps chosen at time $i$. We then obtain that
$$ |X_{n+1}|^2=|X_n|^2+2\langle X_n, \epsilon_{n+1} v_{n+1}\rangle+|v_{n+1}|^2=|X_n|^2+\delta^2+G_{n+1}$$
where, conditioned on $\sigma(X_i,v_i, i=1,\ldots,n, v_{n+1})$, $G_{n+1}$ has mean $0$. Therefore, $|X_n|^2-\delta^2 n$ is a martingale with bounded increments.
Letting $\tau$ denote the exit time, we obtain that
$E(|X_\tau|^2)=\delta^2 E\tau$. But $E|X_\tau|^2\in [1,(1+\delta)^2)$ and hence the conclusion. Note that we actually got that $E\tau\geq 1/\delta^2$.

Now, if you choose the angles to stay on a one dimensional line (ie, choose $\phi_n=\phi=ct.$), then you obtain (if $1/\delta$ is an integer) that $E\tau=1/\delta^2$, so this is the optimal strategy in that case. If $1/\delta$ is not an integer, I don't know if it is actually optimal or only near optimal.

Comment: It seems that the strategy of always choosing a direction perpendicular to the center (which can be executed without knowing where you are!) also achieves the optimal bound of $\frac{1}{\delta^2}$ in the case of $\frac{1}{\delta}$ integer. Actually, it achieves this time deterministically.

Comment: I never claimed uniqueness..... But how do you know the direction perpendicular to the center? For example, after 3 steps where the first was $(\delta,0)$, the second $(0,\delta)$?

Comment: Yes I did not infer uniqueness from your answer. I may be wrong but it seems like by symmetry you always know your orientation with respect to the line toward the center. For example, after the first step you are always a clockwise turn of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ away from the desired perpendicular direction, after the second you are always $\frac{\pi}{4}$ away, etc.

Comment: @NateRiver After the second step, you are $\pi/4$ or $-\pi/4$ away depending on if you went forwards or backwards.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek oh no, you’re right haha.

Comment: Staying on a line is not always optimal. If the largest integer multiple of $\delta$ that is $<1$ is almost, but not quite, equal to $1$, then taking a single step vertically and then moving only horizontally after that is better. (In the first case, we must hit $\pm N$ with a random walk, in the second one, we must reach $\pm (N-1)$ and have wasted a step, but clearly the second scenario is better because any walk that takes us to $N$ in $k$ steps also took us to $N-1$ in $\le k-1$ steps, while the converse is not true.)

Comment: @Christian Remling Reaching $N-1$ does not seem enough to me because $(N-1)^2+1<N^2$ (I am not sure what $N$ is, I assume it is the multiple of $\delta$ that brings you above $1$)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my (admittedly somewhat cryptic) notation. $N$ is the smallest integer with $N\delta\ge 1$. If $(N-1)\delta$ is almost $1$, then $\delta\sqrt{1+(N-1)^2}>1$, so if I start out with a vertical step and then move horizontally only from step $2$ on, leaving the circle is the same as hitting $\pm (N-1)$ with a one-dimensional RW (step size $1$ now) starting at $0$, with one extra step taken at the beginning. Staying on a line is the same as trying to reach $\pm N$, which is clearly worse. (The extra vertical step decreases $E\tau$ by $2/\delta+O(1)$.)

Comment: More generally (and more to the point perhaps), your argument shows that optimizing $\tau$ is the same as minimizing the distance from the circle when we do leave it. As an immediate consequence, staying on a line can not always be best because there are many special situations where we can guarantee to hit the circle exactly with a different strategy.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  I get $\delta^2(1+(N-1)^2)=\delta^2 N^2(1-2/N+2/N^2)$ and I fail to see why this is necessarily larger than $1$. For example, if $\delta=1/N+1/N^3$ and $N$ is large then the above is clearly less than $1$.

Comment: @oferzeitouni: I don't know why you multiply out the square. My assumption was that $(N-1)\delta$ is almost $1$ (let's say $=1-\delta^{1000}$), and $\delta\sqrt{1+(N-1)^2}$ is bigger than this number, by about $\delta/(2(N-1)^2)\simeq \delta^3/2$, so that gets me safely past $1$. Or geometrically: fix a $\delta>0$ in advance. Now it's obviously true that if I go sufficiently close to the circle (but stay inside) along a radius and then take a step of size $\delta$ in the orthogonal direction, I will be outside.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I thought you wrote that  if $(N-1)\delta$ is almost $1$ then $\delta \sqrt{1+(N-1)^2}>1$ (this is literaly what you wrote). I only wanted to point out that this implication is not true. But I agree with the essence of your comment. (In fact, this is an assumption on the relation between $\delta^{-1}$ and  its integer part)